# shell_exec,imagemagick convert pdf to jpg return errors

Tags: php, imagemagick, shell-exec

I use imagemagick convert PDF file to JPG , use PHP `shell_exec('convert ./a.pdf ./a.jpg')`

I get this error:

> Error: /undefined in findresource Operand stack: --dict:15/24(L)-- F3
>   16.0 --dict:6/6(L)-- --dict:6/6(L)-- DroidSansFallback-UniGB-UTF16-H --dict:10/12(ro)(G)-- --nostringval-- CIDFontObject --dict:7/7(L)-- --dict:7/7(L)-- Adobe-GB1 Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop
>   --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 1 1 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
>   --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- %loop_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval--
>   --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %loop_continue Dictionary stack: --dict:1154/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:26/40(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: 2

Command in console is ok.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly related to the PATH - either to `convert` or `ghostscript`. Try converting `a.jpg` to `b.jpg`. If that works, it's the PATH to `ghostscript` that is wrong. If it doesn't work, it is the PATH to `convert` or the script is not getting executed in the folder you think it is.

Comment: @MarkSetchell hi MarkSetchell.I solved problem,I added the code  `putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin");`.that worked properly.thank you

Comment: @MarkSetchell  OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is almost certainly related to the `PATH` - either to `convert` or `ghostscript` (which is required for the `PDF` aspect).

Try the following, which doesn't require `ghostscript`:

```
shell_exec('convert a.jp b.jpg');
```

If that works, it's the `PATH` to `ghostscript` that is wrong.

If it doesn't work, it is the `PATH` to `convert` which is wrong, or the script is not getting executed in the folder you think it is.

As you state in the comments, the following actually solves the problem:

```
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin");
```